# Test Qt app in ios Device

Tags: ios, qt

i've developped an application using QtQuick, it's running great on Android and ios simulator. now i want to test it in iPhone or ios real device.

So do i need to pay for that, or there is a way to test it for free.

In the build file for iosSimulator there a file with the app in the folder "Release-iphonesimulator", will this file work on the device ?

Answer (score 3):

Recently, Xcode 7 beta 4 was released and one of the main features is that you no longer need to pay for deploying to your own device, all you need is your simple apple account.

After you do all the "Configure Device for Development in Xcode" stuff

Using Qt 5.5 (the newest) build your project and before trying to deploy it to your device, go to the place where the build for iphone is, and open it with Xcode 7 beta 4 (the .xcodeproj) and try to run it, it will fail and will ask you if you want to fix the project, say yes and again it will fail but no problem, now go to Qt and you should be able to deploy the app to your iphone. This worked for me!